# How to install Stack Applet?

Tags: unity, software-installation, indicator, applet, stackapplet

I am trying to install Stack Applet. I followed the instructions in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/a/38052) To be specific I used the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/george-edison
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install stackapplet
python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py &
```

When I start Stack Applet via the Dash, nothing happens. (i.e. no window opens.) I tried restarting my computer and starting Stack Applet but that also did not work. How do I install Stack Applet?

EDIT: I tried using Ubuntu Software center with no luck.
My interface looks like so[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried this method of installation :http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17437/how-to-install-stackapplet-on-debian

Comment: @Raphael No, as there is not a Trusty version. (I'm running 14.04) Which should I download? The most recent version?

Comment: Then maybe it is not supported in 14.04

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if anyone else got it to work.

Comment: no i too have the same version and it worked perfectly for me trust me

Comment: but the difference ids i am using gnome version

Comment: Is it possible to migrate it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question here, and I really don't think it is on topic on stack apps.

Comment: @Rinzwind: My name isn't George and I probably frequent Ask Ubuntu as much as Stack Apps.

Comment: @NathanOsman StackApplet support 16.04 or not ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm the author of StackApplet, so hopefully I can help shed some light on what's going on here.

First of all, the version in the Software Center is currently broken. This is because Stack Exchange recently shut down version 1.x of their public API (which StackApplet used). Right before this happened, I updated the source code and release **StackApplet 1.5.2**, which I have tested and can confirm works on Ubuntu 14.04.

Secondly, the new version is available in a PPA, but not the one you included in your question. You need to add the following PPA to your system:

[image] [ppa:stackapplet-dev/stackapplet](https://launchpad.net/~stackapplet-dev/+archive/stackapplet)

After installation, you can confirm that you have the correct version installed by using:

```
dpkg -s stackapplet | grep Version
```

After this is complete, you should be able to run the application directly from the dash.

---

**Edit:** you may also be missing the `python-appindicator` package. You can make sure it is installed by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Comment: Looked really promising. Didn't turn out so, same re I installed via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stackapplet-dev/stackapplet`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and`sudo apt-get install stackapplet`.

`dpkg -s stackapplet | grep Version` returned `Version: 1.5.2-0~201405081543~ubuntu14.04.1`

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: This may be a long shot, but please try closing StackApplet, opening a terminal, running `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`, and then starting StackApplet again.

Comment: It is now installed! However, I'm facing the same issue as this [guy.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484714/how-to-add-an-account-to-stack-applet)

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: I've answered that question.

Comment: May I suggest `python-appindicator` be added as a dependency so that people don't have to ask this question?

Comment: Okay, whole programs works great! I got it to add sites, thanks a bushel.

Comment: @Cammy: You're welcome - glad to hear! That package is listed as a suggested dependency but it should probably be made a requirement. I'll see if I can get that fixed.

Comment: Installed StackApplet, went into settings > add new account, but the sites list is empty, and nothing happens when I click the 'Add Acccount' button. API change ?

Comment: can you add link for PPA for 15.04

Comment: @Nathan Osman Does this work for Ubuntu GNOME? I can't seem to get to work.

Comment: +1 for `python-appindicator` . Thanks!

Comment: I would love to use this indicator applet, but on Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), it's not working. I'm seeing the same 404 as earlier reported. Is this source available to fork or for pull requests? I'm sure the community would contribute if they could...

Comment: @nicorellius the source code is here: https://launchpad.net/stackapplet

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to uninstall your original install of Stack Applet. Then, reinstall it using the Ubuntu Software Center as it is very easy and it worked perfectly for me. I did so in Ubuntu 14.04.
[image]

*edit 
[image]

Comment: Did you do so in 14.04? Also, did you add the PPA first?

Comment: no i just clicked on the install button in sofware centre

Comment: I'm still installing, as I have a slow computer, sorry.

Comment: ok take your time

Comment: It didn't work. It added the program to the launcher and when I opened it nothing happened. Unlock it from the launcher and trying from Dash produced the same result. Running it from the terminal via `/usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py` outputted nothing.

Comment: which desktop environment are you using

Comment: Unity, light-gdm (might be gdm whichever is the default)

Comment: do you get the symbol of stack applet on your screen top i am using GNOME actually

Comment: i have added the symbol of stack applet in my edited answer

Comment: Nope, that is the problem. No window or indicator opens up  on launching the program.

Comment: will you upload a screen shot of your desktop in your question

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: i cant do anything more than this no idea about i it i give up sorry

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version via *`ppa:stackapplet-dev/stackapplet`* as advised, just to find out the problem still resides in the code as I am writing this. A quick check shows the core of the problem you (and I) are experiencing: *stackapplet* is failing to authorize via the following URL:

```
http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites?key=_qlxmEAOH06hLA1_FsZIGQ&jsonp=jQuery1 … 4&_=1 …
```

The call results in a **`404 - Not Found`**.

Until [@nathan-osman](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) (the author) fixes this, or someone else steps in to do the job, there is little hope in being able to use StackApplet.

For informational purposes, here’s a screenshot showing the 404…

[image]