# How to add an account to StackApplet?

Tags: accounts, stackapplet

I have recently installed [StackApplet [image: Install stackapplet]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/stackapplet) and I want to add my account to it. However, I can't do so as I am unable to select a site properly. See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of a site not being selected.]

When I press on the option `Site` nothing appears. Instead, a blank dock appears displaying nothing. Clicking on the dock causes it to disappear.

Comment: there is a subsite dedicated to stack apps: http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug that was fixed literally an hour ago. Assuming you are using the PPA as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/485297/5), you will need to simply wait a few hours for the new version to be published to the PPA.

Comment: Same problem in Ubuntu 14.10, on version: 1.5.2-1

Comment: It is still nor working on 15.04 check it out [this](http://askubuntu.com/posts/618014/edit) @NathanOsman

Answer (score 1):

The problem still resides in the code as I am writing this. A quick check shows the core of the problem you (and I) are experiencing: *stackapplet* is failing to authorize via the following URL:

```
http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites?key=_qlxmEAOH06hLA1_FsZIGQ&jsonp=jQuery1 … 4&_=1 …
```

The call results in a **`404 - Not Found`**.

Until [@nathan-osman](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) (the author) fixes this, or someone else steps in to do the job, there is little hope in being able to use StackApplet.

For informational purposes, here’s a screenshot showing the 404…

[image]