# Add account on STACKAPPLET still broken?

Tags: indicator, 15.04, stackapplet

I have installed StackApplet 1.5.2 with [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stackapplet/1.5.2-1) and python-appindicator. But Still as mentioned in [previous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484714/how-to-add-an-account-to-stack-applet/485339#485339) it is not working!

Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not see a question in his list about stackapplet (?) Nevertheless I PM'd Nathan ;)

Comment: @NewUSer Previous question mentioned is asked by other OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem still resides in the code as I am writing this. A quick check shows the core of the problem you (and I) are experiencing: *stackapplet* is failing to authorize via the following URL:

```
http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites?key=_qlxmEAOH06hLA1_FsZIGQ&jsonp=jQuery1 … 4&_=1 …
```

The call results in a **`404 - Not Found`**.

Until [@nathan-osman](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) (the author) fixes this, or someone else steps in to do the job, there is little hope in being able to use StackApplet.

For informational purposes, here’s a screenshot showing the 404…

[image]