# How to install Stack Applet on 15.04

Tags: software-installation, 15.04

I have download stackapplet from [here](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download) and PPA from from [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stackapplet/1.5.2-1).

I can't follow after this what to do.

I have refered [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484695/how-to-install-stack-applet/485297#485297) question but can't follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installation, confirm that you have installed by using:

```
dpkg -s stackapplet | grep Version
```

If you get a result you should be able to run the application directly from the dash.

NOTE that you have also to install the python-appindicator package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Comment: Thanks but now I am not able to login!!!

Comment: @Freddy you are welcome, What do you mean you are not able to login?

Comment: I mean I can't add account nor can find users!